# Flickering text when using angular translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a main file and some partials which will be included in the main file.I am trying to access the translated content in the main file and the partial files like the below

```
<p>{{ 'HEADLINE' | translate }}</p>
```

translated content from the partial file is not having any flickering issues but the content added in the main file is having flickering issues in the initial load.

As mentioned here (https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading)

"FOUC - Flash of untranslated content :To get around this, you could provide at least one language with your app without having to load it asynchronously."

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    'prefix': 'locale-',
    'suffix': '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

I am following the above approach only so there should not be FOUC.kindly provide some pointers on resolving this.

Main file and the partials share the same controller.

**Update:**

In the main file:

```
 <h1 translate="HEADLINE"></h1>
```

The above code is working perfectly without flickering  but below is flickering

```
   <tabset>
       <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title | translate}}" >
              <div class= "tab-content" ng-include="tab.content" >
              </div>
       </tab>
   </tabset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the below code in the controller and there is no more flickering.

```
     $translate('HEADLINE').then(function (headline) {
            $scope.tabs[0].title = ""+headline;

          }, function (translationId) {
            $scope.tabs[0].title = translationId;
          });
```

And in the main html

```
 <tabset>
   <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" >
          <div class= "tab-content" ng-include="tab.content" >
          </div>
   </tab>
 </tabset>
```